# fread is terminating before accepting all user inputs(from stdin)

Tags: c, buffer, fread

Here is a solution to a CODECHEF Problem "INTEST", which basically tests how fast IO operation is done by a code.

**Input**

The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=107). The next n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than 109, each.

**Output**

Write a single integer to output, denoting how many integers ti are divisible by k.

The following code segment is the fastest C Code submitted so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 65535

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char buffer[SIZE];
    unsigned long n, k, input, count;
    int c, i;
    count = 0;

    scanf("%lu %lu\n", &n, &k);
    input = 0;

    while ((c = fread (buffer, sizeof (char), SIZE, stdin)) > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == '\n')
            {
                //printf("%d\n", input);
                if ((input % k) == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                input = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                input = (input * 10) + (buffer[i] - '0');
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lu\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

They said that fread() offers a faster IO than scanf as fread() does a buffer IO. But when I compile and run it on my own computer(CODEBLOCKS) and give it a few inputs from the console[Note: I am not piping the input file], suppose I enter `4 3` on the first line denoting that 4 more lines follow. But fread() is not even bothering to accept the 4 more lines and after taking one more input basically the program outputs a `0` if I enter a number divisible by 3 or `1` if the number enter is not divisible by 3 and just terminates.

1. Why is fread() terminating before accepting all the inputs?
2. In case of file IO, we can be sure that fread() will read until buffer is full or a file terminator is encountered. But in case of stdin, how long will fread() wait for the user to enter inputs?
3. Why the program is using a buffer of SIZE 65536?

Comment: Be aware that the _first_ `char` read by `fread()` is the `char` immediately after the input for `count`, which may be a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

When the input comes from a terminal, the terminal driver hands data over after each line, and `fread()` only returns what's available.  After the `scanf()`, the first call to `fread()` will likely return just one byte, the newline left behind by `scanf()`.  Thereafter, each call will read a single line, because that's the way the terminal driver works.

By contrast, if the input is a regular file, then the `fread()` call will return as many characters as are available, up to the size of the buffer, completely ignoring newlines as special cases.

If the input is a pipe, then it will read what is available in the pipe at any given time, which might or might not be multiple lines of data, depending on how it is written and whether the reading code keeps up with the writing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int i,n,k,m[50],count;
        printf(" ");
        scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
        count=0;

        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
           printf(" \n");
           scanf("%d",&m[i]);
          
               if(m[i] % k==0){
                count=count + 1;
             }
           
        }
        printf("ans=%d",count);

        return 0;
    }`enter code here`
```